# Page of arbitrary height

Tags: geometry, layout, page, height

Is there a way to have pages of fixed width (e.g. width of A4 or letter format) and arbitrary height? What I mean by that is that you write the content normally and at some point you insert something like `\pagebreak` and a new page starts? The page is as high as needed to fit the content in between `\pagebreak`s.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is 100 km enough? One light year? One megaparsec? Or does `\textheight` truly have to be an “arbitrarily large” length parameter?

Comment: Ideally the page should just be as high as needed but of course within a reasonable range, say maximally the height of 10 normal A4 pages or so. What I want however is that not every page is that high, only that pages are just as high as they need to be. So they could all have different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You fix the `geometry` of first page in the preamble.
Then fix the `newgeometry` of the second page just before the `\newpage`.
Then...

But You:

1. need to know the lenght of each page
2. have the paper to print this?

Comment: Hi thanks. I guess I'll do it manually like this then. I had just hoped to have an "automatic" process for this. I actually don't want to print it, its for digital use only.

Comment: Just a note: `\newgeometry` does only allow to change the layout size but not the paper size.